# Export a table with expandable rows with row colours from json nested data

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, bootstrap-modal

```
input_data = [{
  'row0': [{
    'color': 'danger',
    'item1': 'value1',
    'item2': 'value2',
    'item3': 'value3'
  }, {
    'color': 'active',
    'item4': 'value4',
    'item5': 'value5',
    'item6': 'value6'
  }]
} {
  'row1': [{
    'color': 'danger',
    'item7': 'value7',
    'item8': 'value8',
    'item9': 'value9'
  }, {
    'color': 'active',
    'item10': 'value10',
    'item11': 'value11',
    'item12': 'value12'
  }]
}]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var input_data = [ 
{'row0':
 [
{'color':'danger','item1':'value1','item2':'value2','item3':'value3'},
{'color':'active','item4':'value4','item5':'value5','item6':'value6'}
]},
{'row1': 
[{'color':'danger','item7':'value7','item8':'value8','item9':'value9'},
{'color':'active','item10':'value10','item11':'value11','item12':'value12'}
]} 
];
```

Now you can try the lopping on input_data.length and use that.

Comment: <table class="table" id="resulttable1">
      <thead>
        <tr>
          <th></th>
          <th>Order Numberr</th>
          <th>Order Date</th>
          <th>Total Price</th>
        </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody>
        <tr data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".order1">
          <td>&gt;</td>
          <td>1001</td>
          <td>9/29/2016</td>
          <td>$126.27</td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="collapse order1 danger">
          <td>1</td>
          <td></td>
          <td>Shirt</td>
          <td>$12.27</td>
        </tr>